# UWP Menuflyout programatically doesn't trigger at run time

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I have this XAML

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Button 
        x:Name="BtnTiempo"
        Content="&#xE121;"
        Style="{StaticResource AppBaseButton}"
        Padding="0"
        FontSize="17"
        Foreground="Red">
        <Button.ContextFlyout>
            <MenuFlyout x:Name="TiemposMnu">
                <MenuFlyout.Items>

                </MenuFlyout.Items>
            </MenuFlyout>
        </Button.ContextFlyout>
    </Button>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tiempo.StrDescripcion,FallbackValue=?}" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Right" Foreground="Red"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and this Code that fills **TiemposMnu**

```
    #region Tiempos 
    public List<Tiempo> Tiempos
    {
        get { return (List<Tiempo>)GetValue(TiemposProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TiemposProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Tiempos.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TiemposProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Tiempos", typeof(List<Tiempo>), typeof(ItemDetallePedidoControl), new PropertyMetadata(null,new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTiemposChanged)));

    private static void OnTiemposChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(d is ItemDetallePedidoControl p)
        {
            if (p.Tiempos != null)
            {
                foreach (var tiempo in p.Tiempos)
                {
                    MenuFlyoutItem item = new MenuFlyoutItem()
                    {
                        Text = tiempo.StrDescripcion
                    };
                    item.Click += (s, e1) =>
                    {
                        p.SeleccionarTiempo(tiempo.IntIdTiempo);
                    };
                    p.TiemposMnu.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Everything fires ok. But when I tap / click my button doesn't shows the MenuFlyout.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I tap / click my button doesn't shows the MenuFlyout.

If you want to tap/click the button to show [`MenuFlyout`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlContextMenu) you need to use `Button.Flyout` . Details please see the [remark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyout#remarks) section.

```
<Button.Flyout>
    <MenuFlyout x:Name="TiemposMnu">
        <MenuFlyout.Items>                 
        </MenuFlyout.Items>
    </MenuFlyout>
</Button.Flyout>
```

If you want to trigger the `MenuFlyout` associate with `Button.ContextFlyout`,   right-click (mouse) or press-and-hold (touch) directly on the button. Mode details please reference [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlContextMenu).